# Correct Git clone syntax for SSH

Tags: version-control, git

I'm trying to access a remote git repository using SSH but I'm getting a fatal error - is there a problem with my syntax?

I've created a git repo in the mysite folder on my server - so the repo is at /home/mysite/.git

```
git clone ssh://root@serverIP/mysite/.git
fatal: could not create work tree dir 'mysite'.: Permission denied
```

Can anyone see what is wrong with my syntax or is there another issue here?

Comment: It looks like you have no write permissions inside the directory you are working in.

Comment: @Sgaduuw: No, this is not the problem. His syntax is wrong and git tries to create a repo somewhere.

Comment: Yes the write permissions problem is because i didn't specify a local destination - that issue's gone, now on to new ones :)

Answer (score 2):

Try to use full path for target directory.
For exampple:

```
git clone ssh://root@serverIP/mysite/.git /home/user_name/mysite
```

**UPD:**

When git clones repo it creates directory for it based on repo's name.

```
git clone git@example.com:username/repo.git
```

Git will create directory `repo`.
But there is NO repo name in your case `mysite/.git`.

Answer (score 0):

You must give ssh the whole path to your repo and the.git part is unnecessary, git can figure that one out by itself:

```
git clone ssh://root@serverIP/home/mysite
```

Edited: When using the URL type ssh:// syntax, the colon I used earlier is not valid. 
There is another syntax (ssh style), which needs it:

```
 git clone root@serverIP:/home/mysite
```

I usually prefer the second form.

Comment: thanks for the reply. I can connect ok now but when I try to clone to a local destination I get: warning: You appear to have cloned an empty repository. stdin: is not a tty

Answer (score 0):

A valid ssh URL should look like `ssh://{user}@host.xz/path/to/repo.git`, so you should be ok (if (`mysite/.git` is a valid path).

The issue should be on the local side: do you have write access to your current directory?

---

Once you have write access, you still have two messages:

- `stdin: is not a tty`: that means something in your .bashrc or in the global .bashrc is waiting for an input: see [ee](http://www.site5.com/support/kb/creating-a-new-git-repository/) for example:

> There is a line (`mesg y`) inside the global bashrc file that will cause repeated messages when interacting with GIT (`stdin: is not a tty`)

That would not prevent a clone.

- `warning: You appear to have cloned an empty repository`: that warning is independent from the previous message, and should be accurate if the repo you are cloning is, indeed, an empty one.

Comment: The write permissions issue is sorted, I wasn't specifying a local destination. I now get the error: warning: You appear to have cloned an empty repository.
stdin: is not a tty

Comment: @harry83: Have you added the `/home` part like I told you in my answer? SSH needs it, because it always start at the root directory.

Comment: @SvenW - yes I have the same as you recommended, the full path containing /home/mysite

Comment: @harry83: I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem for me was write access to the directory and I fixed it using "sudo".  I had to create an alias in my bash profile that shorthanded the sudo command before the git command.

Below is the line I added to my .profile file and it works great.  I no longer have the "fatal: could not create work tree dir..." message anymore.

```
alias sgit="sudo /usr/local/git/bin/git"
```

**UPDATE**

I spoke too soon.  Doing this caused other issues with programs on my Mac to save files in the directory since the directory was owned by root.  I had to change the root directory to my user account (which is also admin).  This in turn made my alias to "sudo git" useless since I can now just use git without sudo.  Hope this helps someone.